# How to use alias in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, alias, jooq

Could someone please guide me on how to use alias in jOOQ. I tried looking into jOOQ documentation but it is not clear. Please provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [`org.jooq.Table`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html) and [`org.jooq.Field`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html) types implement [`org.jooq.AliasProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/AliasProvider.html). This means, that you can call [`as(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/AliasProvider.html#as%28java.lang.String%29) on them, to create an aliased object. Example:

```
Table<?> aliasedTable = MY_TABLE.as("t");
Field<?> aliasedField = MY_FIELD.as("f");
```

The examples from the [jOOQ manual](http://www.jooq.org/manual/DSL/ALIAS/) include:

```
TBook book = T_BOOK.as("b");
TAuthor author = T_AUTHOR.as("a");

create.select(author.ID, book.ID)
      .from(author)
      .join(book).on(author.ID.equal(book.AUTHOR_ID))
```