# Selecting fields to join on when joining nested queries

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I've recently been migrating my database and have been moving our remaining SQL queries over to jooq. Having some fun with this one:

```
private SelectQuery<?> getIdeasQuery() {
    Select<?> numComments = dslContext.select(DSL.count().as("comment_count"), COMMENT.IDEA_ID).from(COMMENT).groupBy(COMMENT.IDEA_ID);
    Select<?> numLikes = dslContext.select(DSL.count().as("like_count"), USER_LIKES_IDEA.IDEA_ID).from(USER_LIKES_IDEA).groupBy(USER_LIKES_IDEA.IDEA_ID);

    return dslContext
      .select(DSL.field("comment_count").as("num_comments"))
      .select(DSL.field("like_count").as("num_likes"))
      .select(USER.DISPLAY_NAME)
      .select(USER.AUTHORITY)
      .select(IDEA.fields())
      .from(IDEA.leftOuterJoin(numComments).on(COMMENT.IDEA_ID.eq(IDEA.ID))
                .leftOuterJoin(numLikes).on(USER_LIKES_IDEA.IDEA_ID.eq(IDEA.ID))
                .leftOuterJoin(USER).on(IDEA.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID)))
      .getQuery();
}
```

The returned query is then used to append additional modifiers (using `addConditions()`, `addOrderBy()`, `addLimit()` etc.) depending on the context, and then executed.

The issue I'm having is that the two sub-select queries are not named as their original names for the joins. This is correct behaviour! However, within jOOQ I'm having a hard time finding how I can specify the sub-query's fields to join on. I've tried going down the route of renaming the sub-queries as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859923/how-to-use-alias-in-jooq) StackOverflow answer, but the types don't line up for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've found what I think is a solution for now. However, it seems like a workaround. I've given the sub-queries names when I do the join, and using that name to point to the field. If my schema changes in future, I don't think this will flag up a compile time error.

Here it is for anyone interested:

```
private SelectQuery<?> getIdeasQuery() {
    Select<?> numComments = dslContext.select(DSL.count().as("comment_count"), COMMENT.IDEA_ID).from(COMMENT).groupBy(COMMENT.IDEA_ID);
    Select<?> numLikes = dslContext.select(DSL.count().as("like_count"), USER_LIKES_IDEA.IDEA_ID).from(USER_LIKES_IDEA).groupBy(USER_LIKES_IDEA.IDEA_ID);

    return dslContext
          .select(DSL.field("comment_count").as("num_comments"))
          .select(DSL.field("like_count").as("num_likes"))
          .select(USER.DISPLAY_NAME)
          .select(USER.AUTHORITY)
          .select(IDEA.fields())
          .from(IDEA.leftOuterJoin(numComments.asTable("com")).on(DSL.field("com.idea_id").eq(IDEA.ID))
                    .leftOuterJoin(numLikes.asTable("like")).on(DSL.field("like.idea_id").eq(IDEA.ID))
                    .leftOuterJoin(USER).on(IDEA.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID)))
          .getQuery();
}
```